# Using the same TPU model for training and inference (prediction) in Google Colab

Tags: keras, google-colaboratory, google-cloud-tpu, tpu, google-notebook

I have a code something like this:

```
def getModel():
    model = Sequential()
    model.Add(...)
    .....
    model = tf.contrib.tpu.keras_to_tpu_model(model,
            strategy=tf.contrib.tpu.TPUDistributionStrategy(
            tf.contrib.cluster_resolver.TPUClusterResolver(tpu='grpc://' + os.environ['COLAB_TPU_ADDR'])
        ))
    model.compile(loss='mse',
                  optimizer=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=1e-3, ))
    return model

tpu_model = getModel()
## Main loop
    ....
    tpu_model.predict(states)
    tpu_model.fit(...)
```

Note that I use the same `tpu_model` for batch prediction and training.

`tpu_model.predict()` seems to work fine, but when it runs `tpu_model.fit(...)`, it throws the following error:

```
WARNING:tensorflow:tpu_model (from tensorflow.contrib.tpu.python.tpu.keras_support) is experimental and may change or be removed at any time, and without warning.
INFO:tensorflow:New input shapes; (re-)compiling: mode=infer (# of cores 8), [TensorSpec(shape=(4, 7), dtype=tf.float32, name='dense_6_input_10')]
INFO:tensorflow:Overriding default placeholder.
INFO:tensorflow:Remapping placeholder for dense_6_input
INFO:tensorflow:Started compiling
INFO:tensorflow:Finished compiling. Time elapsed: 1.464857578277588 secs
INFO:tensorflow:Setting weights on TPU model.
...
...
...
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
--> 101         history = tpu_model.fit(states, target_f, epochs=1, verbose=0)
    102         # Keeping track of loss
    103         loss = history.history['loss'][0]

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/keras_support.py in fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1505                                   validation_split, validation_data, shuffle,
   1506                                   class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch,
-> 1507                                   steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1508       finally:
   1509         self._numpy_to_infeed_manager_list = []

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/contrib/tpu/python/tpu/keras_support.py in _pipeline_fit(self, x, y, batch_size, epochs, verbose, callbacks, validation_split, validation_data, shuffle, class_weight, sample_weight, initial_epoch, steps_per_epoch, validation_steps, **kwargs)
   1578         steps_name='steps_per_epoch',
   1579         steps=steps_per_epoch,
-> 1580         validation_split=validation_split)
   1581 
   1582     # Prepare validation data

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_user_data(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size, check_steps, steps_name, steps, validation_split)
    990         x, y, sample_weight = next_element
    991     x, y, sample_weights = self._standardize_weights(x, y, sample_weight,
--> 992                                                      class_weight, batch_size)
    993     return x, y, sample_weights
    994 

/usr/local/lib/python3.6/dist-packages/tensorflow/python/keras/engine/training.py in _standardize_weights(self, x, y, sample_weight, class_weight, batch_size)
   1036     if y is not None:
   1037       if not self.optimizer:
-> 1038         raise RuntimeError('You must compile a model before '
   1039                            'training/testing. '
   1040                            'Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`.')

RuntimeError: You must compile a model before training/testing. Use `model.compile(optimizer, loss)`.
```

As you can see from the logs, there seems to be two modes to run on TPU:
1. `mode=infer`
2. `mode=training`

It seems the both cannot be done simultaneously. Is there any way around this?

I cannot use a Generator because I'm doing Reinforcement Learning where the batch is based on live samples added to a list dynamically from which a batch is sampled, predicted (and certain values are changed) and trained.

Answer (score 0):

I think you can do this following:

- folk the tensorflow keras Adam and add some code into get_update():
  *if self.iterations = 0:

        lr = 0

  else:

         lr = self.lr*
- Use this self-built Adam, build small train data 'data_for_graph_build' with shape = (batchsize, your other shape)
- do *tpu_model.fit(data_for_graph_build,epoch = 1,batch_size = batchsize)*
- finally do your *tpu_model.predict(states)* and *tpu_model.fit(...)*

This seems tricky. I hope it works. but might caused difference as the optimizer weights built on *data_for_graph_build*

Answer (score -1):

Generally you would want to call `fit` before you call `predict` because `fit` trains the model and `predict` uses the trained model to do the predictions. Take a look at these [Cloud TPU Tutorials](https://cloud.google.com/tpu/docs/tutorials) and look at [this guide](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/keras) to understand the Keras API.